# Spring SpEL JPA @Query - getting "QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set" with numeric column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I've a simple Person entity with two fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
    private String name;

    //setter/getters
}
```

A JpaRepository where I override the findAll method to restrict the records based on user role:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {

    @Query("select p from Person p where p.name like ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '%' : principal.username}")
    @Override
    List<Person> findAll();
}
```

The above setup is working fine. But when I update the query to be the following, it throws me exception as below. It looks it failed to parse the SpEL expression.

**Problematic query:**

```
@Query("select p from Person p where p.id like ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '%' : principal.userId}")
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [1] [select p from Person p where p.id like ?1]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 142 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [1] [select p from Person p where p.id like ?1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 156 common frames omitted
```

I played around it and tried the following options, but got the same exception:

1) replacing LIKE with =

`@Query("select p from Person p where p.id = ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '1' : principal.userId}")`

2) Setting hard coded ids :

`@Query("select p from Person p where p.id = ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '6' : '5'}")`

Any suggestions?

FYI :

- I've spring boot 1.3.6.RELEASE, hibernate 4.3.11.Final in my pom.xml.
- I've correctly configured/overridden the
  org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User object to pass the
  userId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there was a conflict between SpEL parser and Spring Data JPA. But I found an workaround it:

**Solution:**
The following change on `@Query` worked just fine:

`@Query("select p from Person p where p.id = ?#{principal.customerId} or 1=?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? 1 : 0}")`